# How to deal with this side effect?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

```
char sign;
cout << "Enter '+' for addition or '-' for subtraction: ";
cin >> sign;
if ( sign != '+' && sign != '-' ) {
     cout << "you can only enter '+' or '-'!\n";
     return 1;
}
```

If I enter `+32423`, the input is still correct to the `cin`(it will pass the checking), because `+` will be automatically set to sign variable, and also `32423` will be stored into my next variable if there is:

```
cin >> number;
```

How can I change the code so that `+32423` is incorrect to the `cin`?

Comment: Use a `string` to get input instead. And check `string == +/-`.

Comment: I don't see any side effect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide exactly what the input you require from the user is and what makes it valid. It sounds to me like you want to accept an entire line of input from the user (so you should use `std::getline` with a `std::string`) and then you want to only accept strings that are exactly `"+"` and `"-"`.

```
std::string sign;
std::getline(std::cin, sign); // Gather input
if (sign != "+" && sign != "-") { // Parse input
  // ...
}
// ...
```

As @H2C03 mentioned, it's a good idea to split up the inputting and the parsing. In this case, the parsing is as simple as comparing the input line to the strings `"+"` and `"-"`.

Comment: So I should use string instead of char and getline instead of cin?

Comment: @Joshua No, you need to use `cin` to get your input. See my edit.

Comment: @JosephMansfield No, he should indeed use `getline()` instead, in order to get one line of input.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to do two things in one step. This is a common error -- don't feel too bad, the designers of the `scanf()` family of funcionts and `std::istream::operator>>` made the exact same mistake.

What you are trying to do: get user input and parse it in order to perform a computation.

What you are **actually** doing: you are doing these inhrenetly different things in one step, and this is making you confused. You should **clearly and cleanly separate the two steps** instead: first, get the user input, and the parse it properly. As in:

```
// get an entire line
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

// parse it: only the format <some digits> <'+' or '-'> <other digits>
// is acceptable, most probably with interspersed whitespace
std::string::iterator it = line.begin();
while (isspace(*it) && it != line.end())
    it++;

std::string::iterator it2 = it;
while (isdigit(*it) && it != line.end())
    it++;

std::string first_number(it2, it); // construct a new substring for the 1st number

// etc. continue the parsing in a similar manner
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they only want to be able to accept a single `+` or a single `-`, so the parsing is as easy as comparing the input line to these two single character strings.

Comment: @JosephMansfield So are you saying that `12345 + 12345` is incorrect too? I don't think that at all it is the case -- OP **very clearly, *very obviously*** wants to perform some arithmetic. But even then -- why bother? My advice about "do it in two steps" **still applies,** and it's even easier to realize then.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's incorrect too. They just want the operator. They'll get the operands next.